# Is a self join no different than joining 2 different tables, in terms of performance

Tags: mysql, self-join

Is a self join no different than joining 2 different tables, in terms of performance?  In case indexes exist for the joining columns. If so, does that still hold true for a table with 700 million records

Comment: what is unclear here?

Answer (score 1):

A self join is no different than joining different tables.

Comment: What is the reasoning behind it? Does that still hold true, if the table 2 is just 5% the size of table 1. We are joining table1 to table 2

Comment: now you seem to be comparing two database designs and asking which is more efficient; you'd need to give a whole lot more information to get a meaningful answer to that.  but as a rule, don't put things that really fit in one table into a new table just for efficiency unless you really have to.  and sometimes the only way to find out if you do is to try and see